# Simplest way of reading a file from clients computer?

Tags: javascript, html

i need to read a txt file from clients and then send it to my server in a form input? What is the simplest way to achieve this? Also i don't want to send it as a file, i want to send it as a string in an input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to send it as an uploaded file. However, this does not require you to save the stream of bytes into a file on your server. You can process it directly in your serverside application.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any mature APIs for reading files right now across all browsers, however if you use webkit-based browsers or Firefox there are options.

Here's a tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/